# Difference between "default gradle wrapper " and "local gradle distribution" in android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In android studio when we build the project there are two options for building the project in:

> settings->build Tools->Gradle->Project-level settings

The first option is **"Use default gradle wrapper"** and the second option is **"Use local gradle distribution"**

My question is which option is faster and when will it be used?

Comment: As per my knowledge, "default gradle" is the one that is packaged with the project. This is done so everyone in the team uses the same version. Local gradle is the one you have on your system.

Comment: "Faster" depends on the Gradle version number, the specs of the computer, and whether the Gradle Daemon is used.

Answer (score 19):

You can read about Gradle Wrapper in the [official user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).

The main thing about the wrapper - it cares about the Gradle version used to build your project. So, if one has configured the project to use a wrapper, then everyone will build it with the same version of Gradle. The version of Gradle could be specified in the configuration file called `gradle-wrapper.properties`.

One more important thing is that Gradle distribution will be included in your project and if someone will try to build it, no local Gradle installation will be needed.

But if you choose **use local gradle distribution**, then your project will be built with the version of Gradle you have currently installed and it doesn't guarantees, that your project will be built correctly, since Gradle version may differ.

I don't think, that time is different for this two cases, but wrapper usage seems to be preferable. Sure, in this case, you have to store wrapper distribution in your version control system, but you can set build tool version exactly used to build your project and make no one install Gradle manually if he doesn't have Gradle installed yet.

Comment: Suppose someone checkout my code which was build using default Gradle wrapper settings. But his/her android studio already selected local Gradle distribution settings. Then, does it build properly on that PC? What happen for vice-versa also?

Comment: This is project speecific property and you have to select it every time you import some project into you IDE. If someone rejected to use wrapper, though it was available for the project, then it's at one's own risk. Project may fail to build (but may be not), because your build script could be made with the Gradle version, which could be incompatible with this local version.

Answer (score 7):

I want to add a very important point to the Stanislav's answer. Gradle could be used not only for building your project from Android Studio, but also the from command line. This is especially important if you want to build it in CI environment. In that case, you don't need to care about specific gradle version on your server. The project will be built with the same version for both IDE and CI and this will make your build stable and predictable.